# How to start Windows 8 Camera from AIR?

Tags: .net, windows-8, air, windows-8.1, air-native-extension

I have an cross-platform AIR mobile app that uses the native camera-app on various platforms.

This is working fine on iOS, Android, BB10 etc.

When using it on Windows 8.1, I don't get a supported device via the flash.media.CameraUI, thus there's one in my tablet.

(Yes, I'm aware AIR is not supported on Modern UI, the app runs on Desktop, and this is fine for me ;-)

Is there a way to start the CameraCaptureUI (or an equivalent) from AIR?

I'm willing to use a native extension if necessary, but don't have any experience in coding for Windows 8, so I don't know where to start. I looked at the example anes from the adobe homepage, but those are coded in C, C++ or C#, and I'm mostly familiar with as and java.

I get stuck right at the beginning, when I try to create an .dll for the ane, I'm not allowed to reference any UI elements (as CameraCaptureUI) in it.

Many thanks,
Timm

EDIT: Seems I have to clarify the question a little: So it is:

How can I use the native Windows Camera App without flash.media.CameraUI ?

Comment: What is your problem here? Don't you know how to use the Camera API of Adobe AIR or what?

Comment: @PaulFacklam Hi, the problem is, the CameraUI doesn't work on Windows 8(.1), at least at no devices I have tested. (Gives back: 'camera.isSupported = false;' ). To clarify the question: How can I start the native Windows Camera app WITHOUT using flash.media.CameraUI?